# Had Moses resurrected already in the holy mountain?

Tags: luke, moses, resurrection

Luke 9:30

> Two men, Moses and Elijah, appeared in glorious splendor, talking with
>   Jesus.

Moses died long time ago. Had Moses resurrected already in the holy mountain? Because he was talking with Jesus.

Comment: @NigelJ Please don't use comments to answer questions.

Comment: What makes you think he was resurrected?

Comment: @SolaGratia   `talking with Jesus`. Only living person can talk....

Comment: Then how did Christ preach to the spirits in prison when He physically died on the cross? You don't need a body to live. Indeed, "God is not the God of the dead, but of the living." Jesus was speaking about Abraham, Isaac and Jacob here. See also 2 Macc. 15:13-14: "After this there appeared also another man, admirable for age, and glory, and environed with great beauty and majesty: then Onias answering, said: This is a lover of his brethren, and of the people of Israel: this is he that prayeth much for the people, and for all the holy city, Jeremias the prophet of God."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that Moses (and Elias) appeared (the verb is ὁράω [Strong 3708](https://biblehub.com/greek/3708.htm)) and then after the overshadowing of a cloud, they disappeared and Jesus was found alone, Luke 9:36, strongly suggests that this was not a substantial, physical resurrection but an 'appearance' or manifestation.

Jesus Christ is the first to rise from the dead in resurrection as Paul states in Colossians 1:18 :

> And he is the head of the body, the church: who is the beginning, **the firstborn from the dead**; that in all things he might have the preeminence.

It is Christ who rises first and, thus, has pre-eminence over all.

Instances of temporary resurrection (such as Lazarus and others) are only indicative of permanent resurrection. The final and unending resurrection being here suggested for Moses is inappropriate for it is Jesus Christ who **first** arises and dies no more.